# Testing file matching in pyspark

Tags: testing, pyspark

I have a [SparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.html) and a bunch of files that I want to access using the [textFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.textFile.html?highlight=textfile#pyspark.SparkContext.textFile) method. The logic to find which files I need to access is complex and requires careful testing.

In my testing environment (using pytest), all the python files and files the `SparkContext` needs to access are on my local machine. The problem I encounter is that creating a `SparkContext` object in this testing environment and loading data using `textFile` often fails with a timeout exceeding 1 minute (cf [Mock a Spark RDD in the unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944931/mock-a-spark-rdd-in-the-unit-tests)).

In my testing environment, how to test that the file patterns I send to `textFile` are right, and therefore ensure that `textFile` returns an `rdd` from the right files?